# Не работает авторизация на сайте

Tags: php, авторизация

Выходить ошибка ***неверный логин или пароль***, даже если все верно

Обработкич auth.php

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    define('myeshop', true);
    include('db_connect.php');
    include('../functions/functions.php');

    $login = clear_string($_POST["login"]);

    $pass   = md5(clear_string($_POST["pass"]));
    $pass   = strrev($pass);
    $pass   = strtolower("9nm2rv8q".$pass."2yo6z");



    if ($_POST["rememberme"] == "yes")
    {

            setcookie('rememberme',$login.'+'.$pass,time()+3600*24*31, "/");

    }


   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reg_user WHERE (login = '$login' OR email = '$login') AND pass = '$pass'",$link);
If (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['auth'] = 'yes_auth'; 
    $_SESSION['auth_pass'] = $row["pass"];
    $_SESSION['auth_login'] = $row["login"];
    $_SESSION['auth_surname'] = $row["surname"];
    $_SESSION['auth_name'] = $row["name"];
    $_SESSION['auth_patronymic'] = $row["patronymic"];
    $_SESSION['auth_address'] = $row["address"];
    $_SESSION['auth_phone'] = $row["phone"];
    $_SESSION['auth_email'] = $row["email"];
    echo 'yes_auth';

}else
{
    echo 'no_auth';
}  
} 

?>
```

```js
if (auth_pass == "" || auth_pass.length > 15 )
 {
    $("#auth_pass").css("borderColor","#FDB6B6");
    send_pass = 'no';
 }else { $("#auth_pass").css("borderColor","#DBDBDB");  send_pass = 'yes'; }



 if ($("#rememberme").prop('checked'))
 {
    auth_rememberme = 'yes';

 }else { auth_rememberme = 'no'; }


 if ( send_login == 'yes' && send_pass == 'yes' )
 { 
  $("#button-auth").hide();
  $(".auth-loading").show();

    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/include/auth.php",
  data: "login="+auth_login+"&pass="+auth_pass+"&rememberme="+auth_rememberme,
  dataType: "html",
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {

  if (data == 'yes_auth')
  {
      location.reload();
  }else
  {
      $("#message-auth").slideDown(400);
      $(".auth-loading").hide();
      $("#button-auth").show();

  }

}
});  
}
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что в логе ошибок? Какая версия PHP? Что на самом деле отдает сервер по AJAX запросу (`no_auth` или что-то еще)?

Comment: Идеология security through obscurity предполагает, что вы **нигде и никогда** не расшарите код.. Теперь меняйте алгоритм)

Comment: Версия PHP 5.5, echo 'no_auth';